# Wait for observable on component to finish on another component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a layout component which look like this :

```
<div class="wrapper" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; padding: 0" >
    <app-header  style="flex: none;"></app-header>

    <div  style="flex: 1 0; position: relative;">
        <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate()" ></router-outlet>

        <app-footer *ngIf="showFooter"></app-footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have an "activate" event which should check the 'token' every route changing.

The problem start when token in the localStorage is expired and before its update him on the "activate" event another OnInit post request on the new page send a request with the old header which cause an error.

For example I have this function on my home-component

```
this.serverRequest.getTrainingsFromTo(weekBoundry.from.getTime(), weekBoundry.to.getTime()).subscribe((trainings: ITrainingInfo[]) => {

                console.log(`trainings : ${trainings}`)
                if (trainings) {
                    // Ensure server sent just this week's trainings
                    var filteredTrainings: ITrainingInfo[] = trainings.filter((ti) => {
                        return ti.finishTime >= weekBoundry.from.getTime() && ti.finishTime < weekBoundry.to.getTime();
                    });

                    filteredTrainings.forEach((ct: ITrainingInfo) => {
                        var index: number = new Date(ct.finishTime).getDay();
                        this.weekDaysWithTrainings[index] = true;
                        this.trainingsThisWeek = this.weekDaysWithTrainings.reduce(function (total, x) { return x == true ? total + 1 : total }, 0)

                    });
                }

            }, error => { });
```

And because the header is with a wrong token , the request failed.
I read a few answers , and tried to work with async await but nothing helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RouteGuard and call API and return true or false.

```
canActivate() {
    // call API to validate Token
   // If Validate token runs correctly return true
   // else return false

}
```

Make sure to include Guard to route module as well with key **canActivate**
Example

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [Guard] },
```

Comment: Thanks But how can I return an answer from the observable to the canActivate function?

Comment: You can create a subject and emit it from CanActivate